# Physical properties of niobium pentoxide ($\mathrm{Nb}_2\mathrm{O}_5$) for thermal simulation

Tags: thermodynamics, resource-recommendations, material-science, data

I am looking all day long for heat capacity, thermal conduction, and expansion coefficient of niobium-pentoxide. I want to conduct a thermal (heat flow) analysis on this and need it as input data.
Can anyone provide the data or give references where to find it?

Answer (score 1):

[Heat capacity](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?Name=Nb2O5&Units=SI&cTC=on) of $Nb_2O_5$ from NIST's database, for a wide range of temperatures using Shomate equations.

But thermal conductivity and thermal expansion coefficient will be very hard to find.

Comment: @Eisbär: I suggest to try and find thermal conductivity and thermal expansion coefficient for a compound that is *similar* to $Nb_2O_5$ and use these values in your modelling. Please upvote if you liked the answer. Ta.

Comment: That was a good advice. Ta2O5 seems pretty similar. For this one can find values. I'm going to use those.

Comment: @Eisbär: excellent.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible source of data:

[Thin films and nanostructures of niobium pentoxide: fundamental properties, synthesis methods and applications](http://pubs.rsc.org/En/content/articlelanding/2014/ta/c4ta02561j#!divAbstract)

Abstract:

> As one of the transition metal oxides, niobium pentoxide (Nb2O5) offers a broad variety of properties that make it a potentially useful and highly applicable material in many different areas. In comparison to many other transition metal oxides, Nb2O5 has received relatively little attention, which presents a significant opportunity for future investigations aimed at fundamentally understanding this material and finding new and interesting applications for it. In this article, a general overview of Nb2O5 is presented which focuses on its fundamental properties, synthesis methods and recent applications, along with a discussion on future research directions relevant to this material.

This suggests that the article may contain references that will further help. I was not able to access it without paying - but maybe your institution's library can help you.

Comment: Thanks. Good idea. I can check at the university it seems to have online access to the journal.

Comment: In this book:**Thermal Conductivity: Theory, Properties, and Applications** there is a chapter on thin films where thermal conductivities are stated.

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone looking for the answer in future. I will use this values:

k=0.3 W/m/K (thin film value from Ta2O5)
Cp=600J/kg/K (taken from NIST **thanks Floris**)
roh=4500kg/m^3
TEC=5*10^-6 (thermal expansion coefficient of Ta2O5)

Answer (score 0):

In https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00587621/document , the value for the thermal conductivity of Nb2O5 is 1 W/mK.

Comparing to the thermal conductivity of TaO (http://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.4926921) the values are nearly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this publication - there are temperature-dependent thermal conductivity values for Nb2O5 (niobiumpentoxide):
https://www.mdpi.com/1996-1073/12/4/610